# Graph relation between User and Post

Tags: database, data-structures, graph, neo4j, data-modeling

Is it a good approach to make relationship with all the User in the system with a Post when a user create it with visibility as everyone? Like one(Post) to many(User) mapping.

Or what will be the best approach?

Comment: Nest approach for what?

Comment: Best approach to give relation based on visibility between User and Post.